# Thanks for checking this video out VS checking out this video

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs, objects

I heard both phrases in some YouTube videos and I am not sure which one's correct.

Apart from the answer, could you tell me what I should be googling for in order to understand the grammar related to this question?

*I don't think it's a duplicate and I don't understand why it's marked as one.* Please note that this is not the "check" vs "check out" question. I use "check out" in my example. The question here is the order of words; where comes the object,  between "check" and "out" or after "check out". As far as I know, it's a phrasal verb and I wanted to know where the object should come: before or after the particle? *At the moment of asking this question, I didn't know it's called "phrasal verb" so it was difficult to find related articles on Google.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the first one is incorrect per se, but it's definitely not the common usage. "Thanks for checking out this video" is the way to go.

As for searching the answer yourself, a first step is simply googling the two phrases you see and seeing how many results you get, and what those results look like. In this case, searching Google for "Thanks for checking this video out" I get your question, and a bunch of results that say "checking out this video".

(I would add that because "checking this video out" is less common usage it also sounds like it has a different meaning - not so much a casual way of saying "watch this video", but more like a suggestion you actually need to *check* something *out*, i.e. there's something weird about the video that needs to be investigated, or a technical problem they want you to solve)

Answer (score 0):

'To check out' is a two-word phrase that means; 'to inspect', although it's more informal. It also implies that there is something to be discovered, and that the *checker* is experiencing something new. You check out a film by watching it for the first time at the theatre, but subsequent viewings would not be classed as 'checking it out'.

In your title, you have given two options. I believe both of them to be correct, but I find it a little awkward when two-word phrases like that are split down the middle. Do you see how the first option has "this video" placed in between the words "check" and "out"?

"Thank for checking out this video" sounds more natural.